# npm request module--return a value

Tags: node.js, request, asynccallback

In one of the examples in the request's documents shows this example:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#custom-http-headers

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {
  url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/request/request',
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'request'
  }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var info = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(info.stargazers_count + " Stars");
    console.log(info.forks_count + " Forks");
  }
}

request(options, callback)
```

Lets' say I want the value of the variable info return to me.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot pass a value from an asynchronous command. The most common strategy used in Node.js is to wrap the code that requires the `info` variable in a function and call that from the callback.

eg:

```
function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    functionThatUsesInfo(info);
  }
}
```